# Displaying both numeric and text values in Label using Arcade?

Tags: labeling, arcgis-online, arcade

I am using ArcGIS Online.

I had created [this label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEqdZ.jpg) using Arcade because I had to customize the wind speed outcome from km/h to mph. I wanted to add "mph" to label after the wind speed value, but am not having any luck with the Text function in Arcade.

Can someone help me with this task?

```
$feature.WIND_SPEED / 1.6;
```

Answer (score 2):

As [commented by @Hornbydd](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/437621/displaying-both-numeric-and-text-values-in-label-using-arcade#comment714331_437621):

> Try `Text($feature.WIND_SPEED / 1.6) + " mph";`